# Stack overflow exception without infinite loop (as far as I can tell)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, entity-framework-4, stack-overflow

I have a stack overflow error, and I'm fairly sure I don't have any kind of infinite recursion (at least I've stared at the error for a few hours now and I can't imagine how its looping infinitely).

Here is the code:

```
    public decimal? Amount
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_savedWork.Amount))
                return decimal.Parse(_savedWork.Amount);
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                _savedWork.Amount = value.Value.ToString();
                Percent = null;
            }
            else
                _savedWork.Amount = "";
            OnPropertyChanged("Amount");
        }
    }
```

**#Note I have a string housed in a nullable decimal, that's why I'm converting it. Please don't make me go into why I'm doing this.**

the line `savedWork.Amount = value.Value.ToString()` is where I get the error.

Basically I'm thinking that my stack is just too small (or my code is too big I suppose). **I basically run this code twice, and it works when in one form, but not when I make another form and place it in there, so I think the difference between these 2 forms is tipping the stack.**

Is there a way to identify what I'm doing wrong? I want to find out what part of the code is taking up a too much or is persisting too long etc.

I've done some research about how the stack/heap work and I know about PerfMon.exe, but as far as I know it only works for the heap. Is there a similar tool that I can use for the stacks my program is running?

I found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8e6db1e6-e429-4b4f-9ac6-5e848604188b/) about 2 tools called *windbg* and *cdb* but I can't find much about how to install/use them. Are these tools the right way to go?

Alternatively if there is an infinite loop or something that would be great.

## Edit

here is the code requested for the Amount Property (its autogenerated by EntityFramework) as I said in the comments, the step into doesn't even reach here. I really do think my stack limit is just being reached.

```
  public global::System.String Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return _Amount;
        }
        set
        {
            OnAmountChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Amount");
            _Amount = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Amount");
            OnAmountChanged();
        }
    }
```

## Final Edit

Ok so **Meta-Knight**'s answer showed me that I did indeed have an infinite loop. I had an event handler subscribed to the PropertyChanged event of the DisplayTypeOfInvestment (the class that the Amount Property belongs to). The handler looked like this:

```
 void DisplayTypeOfInvestmentList_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            _typeOfInvestmentFormSavedWork.TypeOfInvestment.Clear();
            foreach (DisplayInvestmentFund d in _displayInvestmentFundList)
            {
                _typeOfInvestmentFormSavedWork.TypeOfInvestment.Add(d.SavedWork);
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("TypeOfInvestmentFormSavedWork");

    }
```

The `TypeOfInvestmentFormSavedWork` is a completely different class that contains in it it's own version of the SavedWork class that we see that is used an the Amount property. The point of this method was to update this TypeOfInvestmentFormSavedWork property to the new value of _savedWork when the Amount property changes. For some reason this is triggering the DisplayTypeOfInvestment viewmodel's PropertyChanged. I didnt figure it out but I changed the method to look like this:

```
 void DisplayTypeOfInvestmentList_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Amount" || e.PropertyName == "Percent")
        {
            _savedWork.TypeOfInvestment.Clear();
            foreach (DisplayInvestmentFund d in _displayInvestmentFundList)
            {
                _savedWork.TypeOfInvestment.Add(d.SavedWork);
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentWork");
        }
    }
```

The if statement stops the weird properties being changed in the DisplayInvestmentFund when the Add method is called.

I realise this answer doesnt make much sense, but for me to explain this in full detail would take a *very* long time. I also realise that this probably means my code is bad. I'm not sure what to do about that. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to confirm there is no infinite recursion?

Comment: what it's your OnPropertyChanged("Amount");?

Comment: What is `_savedWork`?  Is it an instance of this class, or does it contain a member of this class?  Smells like infinite recursion to me too.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is happening without additional information. What type is _savedWork, and what type is the current property a member of, etc.

Comment: Since `_savedWork.Amount` is a string, it is clearly a different class.

Comment: I'm assuming _savedWord.Amount calls the same property its written in. Hence infinite loop

Comment: What is _savedWork?  I'm wondering if the assignment of the Amount property is causing a recursive loop.

Comment: please post the code of `_savedWork.Amound`, and all methods subscribed to `PropertyChanged`

Comment: @jrummel I have stepped through the code and it doesnt loop. t just crashes on that line.

Comment: Did you step into or step over? Try stepping into.

Comment: @ExitMusic use Step Into on that line not Step Over

Comment: @jrummell I meant step into soz, Tried pressing F11 and also pressing the step into button on the toolbar. Still crashes at that place

Comment: @CodeInChaos in terms of what is subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event its just the controls in the view that is bound to the `ObservableCollection<DisplayInvestmentFund>` collection. If you really want I can post the xaml of the view but I am sooo certain its not that because as said in the post, when i place the view in one form it works but when i create another form to host the view with and show that one it crashes.

Comment: @ExitMusic, Since you're using Xaml, please tag your question with either Silverlight or WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a recursive call to the `Amount` setter somehow. You could debug it by "stepping into" the properties instead of stepping over. If you set VS so that it doesn't step into properties, you can still put a breakpoint inside your setters to simulate a "step into". As for VS not stepping into .edmx files, as CodeInChaos mentioned, maybe the class is tagged with a [DebuggerStepThrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: I revised my question to explain why this is the answer

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you're assigning to `Amount` in one of the event handlers that `OnPropertyChanged` calls.

Another possibility is that you have code in the setter of `SavedWork.Amount` that calls `YourClass.Amount` again.

---

But why don't you just debug it? Just step through the code in the Visual Studio debugger.

The stack trace should also be useful. With endless recursion you typically get a repeating sequence of methods. If my guess is correct the repeated part will be something like:

```
MyClass.set_Amount
MyClass.OnPropertyChanged
OtherClass.myClass_amount_changed
```

Comment: Yes, you don't need windbg or PerfMon or any other special tool, just use the VS debugger! With stack trace, breakpoints and step-by-step debugging you can figure out what's going on.

Comment: I cant step through it. As I step over the line where I assign it it just breaks. Also the SavedWork is an EntityObject, so It doesnt really have a PropertyChanged in it. I'll post what subsribes to the PropertyChanged, but It doesnt really get that far.

Comment: @ExitMusic The most likely bug candidate is the code inside `savedWork.set_Amount`. So please post that code.

Comment: @ExitMusic: You could "step into" the properties instead of stepping over. If you set VS so that it doesn't step into properties, you can still put a breakpoint inside your setters to simulate a "step into".

Comment: @Meta-Knight thanks for that. I don't know why but the debugger doesn't step into the designer of the .edmx Your suggestion showed me I have an event handler subscribing to something in the designer. There is a infinite loop, just need to figure out whats happening there. Make an answer so I can give you the vote.

Comment: @ExitMusic Possibly because the auto generated code code is tagged with `DebuggerStepThrough` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Is the class of which Amount member of the same type as _savedWork?

Because there could be this loop:

1) You assign a value to Amount

2) Before the value is set, you assign a value to _savedWork.Amount

3) Before the value of _savedWork.Amount is set, the line is triggered again

4) Before the value of _savedWork._savedWork.Amount is set...

5) Before the value of _savedWork._savedWork._savedWork.Amount is set...

And this goes to infinity and beyond.

Comment: `_savedWord != this`. `_savedWork.Amount ` is a string, `value.Amount` a `Decimal?`

Comment: The two properties are different, but if they each set the other in their code then you still have infinite recursion, it's just switching between two setters forever, rather than staying inside of one.

Comment: The one item is an EntityObject created by EntityFramework. Its setter has no reference to this one's

Answer (score 0):

Is `_savedWork` an object of the same type as the `Amount` property you listed? Because that *will* give you a stack overflow error! In that case, you need to find a way to talk about `Amount` without invoking the `get`ter and `set`ter.

Comment: `_savedWord != this`. `_savedWork.Amount ` is a string, `value.Amount` a `Decimal?`