# Entity Framework strange behavior

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-database-first

I recently added a new field`("Category")` to a database table. Updated the model from Database. When I make a query and get a collection of this table I try to add a value to this field. I am not event saving it at this point. The program runs like it is in infinite loop. When I stop the debugger it is on the `ReportPropertyChanged("Category")` of the model designer code. If I step into code it goes into the `Get` portion of another field and just gets stuck in this `Get` loop - very strange. I have Cleaned/Rebuilt solution, deleted the model and reattached with the behavior remaining. I have successfully added fields in the past without this strange result, any ideas?

Winforms, EF 4.0.

Line of code (location of problem):

```
rec.Category = category
```

Comment: Hi, have you altered any of the generated entity code? Also what version of Entity Framework are you using? Are you using Code First or Database first?

Comment: Database first, if I comment out the code where I set this field all runs fine.

Comment: Thanks, could you add the line of code (or example of) where you are setting the field. Also are you using asp.net, winform etc? Also what version number are you using e.g. Entity Framework 6?

Comment: Thanks is the category an object? i.e. are you trying to create a foreign key like relationship? Also are you generating DbContext code or ObjectContext?

Comment: nvarchar(10) so `string`

Comment: No relationships here

Comment: `DbContext code or ObjectContext?` - not sure. I make an instance of the `EntityContainer` - from what I can see.

Comment: Is the problem present when running without the debugger attached onto the process?

Comment: Problem exist in both debugging and instance.

Comment: Do you have another entity that has a `Category` field ?

Comment: No I do not, thanks for helping!

Comment: Looks like I am using the `DbContext` object.

Comment: @OneFineDay Have you deleted the EDMX file completely and "Run Custom" tool afterwards ? Also, are you using source control ? Perhaps checking out the complete solution directory while doing it is needed, sometimes these tools fail on read only directories/files without whining much.

Comment: I did delete it completely, I did *not* `Run Custom Tool` after, and I have never done that. I will try it if you think it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds that perhaps there is an event listener where you are inadvertently changing the property again.

Perhaps try setting a breakpoint in the setter of the generated code, as suggested by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9005656/141022 to try and spot the loop.

And turning of step over properties in the visual studio debugger settings.

And perhaps removing the DebuggerStepThrough from the generated code temporarily (if it's there) to see if you can step into the property.

The linked answer (although not directly related) may give you some hints.

Perhaps the callstack might give you some hints as well, but I'm guessing it could be tricky to read if it's across threads.

Comment: I am setting this field one time for each record in a loop - nothing unusual - I do that with other fields.

Comment: Did the call stack or stepping into the setter with the debugger show anything amiss?

Comment: only that it kept running a Get loop on a diff field right after I stopped it as mentioned above. Nothing else looked amiss.

Comment: Did you get a chance to disable 'step over properties and operators' in the debugger?

Comment: That is weird how that fixes this.

Comment: That's very strange I wouldn't expect it to fix it, just help enable you to spot the problem. It sounds as though you may have a visual studio debugger plugin or perhaps a debugger visualiser or something similar causing trouble.

Comment: I always have weird stuff that makes me bring these questions here just to find out that they are weird. Dunno!